# Shipping & Handling Electronics & Electro-mechanical parts

Tags: safety, esd, damage

What are common packaging(Shipping & Handling) guidelines (specs/stds) for Electronics & Electro-mechanical parts? Currently, working on adding onto our current generic guidelines for packaging aircraft parts. When it comes to electrical related components, we have some basic common sense packaging solutions. I think it's best to not re-invent the wheel in this scenario.

Comment: Many places selling electronics have a zero-return policy.  You might need anti-static bags

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that you should use static-dissipative bags (the metallic-looking plastic ones, not the pink plastic "antistatic" ones) when you're shipping static-sensitive devices.

Comment: There's also [static proof foam](https://www.uline.com/Grp_143/Anti-Static-Foam) which is like a pink looking foam that is commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an electrical repository for questions, I'm not going to speculate on the mechanical part of the question.

You need to protect your components from three things:

1) ESD, get the mylar bags, the polypropolene (pink or blue) do not provide adequate ESD protection if scratched (the ESD layer wears off)

2) Humidity, Make sure you look at [MSL levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moisture_sensitivity_level) of your electronic parts (yes, all of them on the PCB) and provide adequate protection.

3) Vibration. See if there are any vibe limits on components (usually specified in g force or newtons) , if there is you will have to design packaging to shield them from worst case vibe during shipping.